# Collect from only between onResume and onPause Android

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow

I have a HomeActivity with a TabLayout and 3 fragments. OneFragment, TwoFragment, ThreeFragment. In the HomeViewmodel i have a StateFlow which takes a value and OneFragment collects the result and then opens a Dialog popup.

Custom flow class

```
class PrivateEventStateFlow<T> {
    private val _event = MutableStateFlow<T?>(null)
    val event = EventStateFlow()

    fun setValue(value: T) {
        _event.value = value
    }

    inner class EventStateFlow {
        /**
         * State flow of the encrypted touch id token
         */
        val eventFlow = _event.asStateFlow()
        fun eventConsumed() {
            _event.value = null
        }

        /**
         * Collect event and consume it automatically
         */
        fun collectEvent(
            owner: LifecycleOwner,
            onCollect: suspend (T) -> Unit
        ) {
            eventFlow.collect(owner) {
                if (it == null) return@collect
                eventConsumed()
                onCollect(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel

```
private val _navigationAction = PrivateEventStateFlow<NavigationAction>()
val navigationAction = _navigationAction.event


private fun doRequest() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Here i do a request...!!
            when (useCaseRequest()) {
                false -> Unit
                true ->
                    _navigationAction.setValue(
                        NavigationAction.ShowBottomSheet
                    )
            }
        }
    }
```

OneFragment

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                viewModel.navigationAction.collectEvent(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                    when (it) {
                        NavigationAction.ShowBottomSheet -> {
                            navigateToTransferLimits()
                        }
                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, while the viewModel waits for the response, the user might have been navigated to another Tab. The result that the DialogPopup appears even when the OneFragment is not visible. I want the popup to show only when the OneFragment is visible. If the user navigates to another fragment then i want the popup to be shown when he navigates back to OneFragment.
The `repeatOnLifecycle` supposed to collect event only between two lifecycle states. As i have logged in the OneFragment, the states that are being called when the user navigates in and out of OneFragment are onResume() <-> onPause(). I have tried all the possible Lifecycle.States but none of them works.

How can i collect the event only when the fragment is Visible?

Comment: What does the `collectEvent` function look like?

Comment: I am guessing, but maybe since these fragments are in a tab layout, they are not dropping to paused state when you switch tabs, so `repeatOnLifecycle` isn't helping prevent the flow from getting collected when you're on another tab. So you will have to add an if-statement to check if this fragment is the currently shown tab.

Comment: 1) When you change Tab, the onPause is called. And when you get back to the Tab the onResume is called. However, none of the Lifecycle.States seems to prevent the Flow from collecting. But even if i add an IF statement, how can i show the Dialog when the user comes back to the Tab since the flow will have been already collected?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using just MutableStateFlow (and not the custom one) and lifecycleScope just like the following example shows.
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda